# Variable is not updating

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Problem:

A `List<>` variable is passing a reference check even though there is no accessible data in the list.

Solution:

The Save() function finished executing before the save thread had finished causing the thread to abort.
added `threadrunning = true` before starting the thread.

Code:

```
Thread saveThread;
public string filepath;
public string rootElementName;
public string objectElementName;
public int objectsSaved;
public SaveData saveData;
public List<SavedObject> datasets;
public bool threadRunning = false;
public bool syncingData = false;

public void StartSaveThread()
{
    bool warned = false;

    //The "error" is here
    //The reference returns true but none of the data is accessible, there is nothing in the list
    while(datasets != saveData.objects)
    {
        if(warned == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for data to sync");
            syncingData = true;
            warned = true;
        }
    }

    syncingData = false;

    saveThread = new Thread(SaveData);
    saveThread.Start();
}

public void SaveData()
{
    bool saveComplete = false;
    threadRunning = true;

    while (threadRunning && saveComplete == false)
    {
        objectsSaved = 0;

        XmlDocument saveFile = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement documentRoot = saveFile.CreateElement(rootElementName);

        foreach (SavedObject dataset in datasets)
        {
            XmlElement savedObjectElement = saveFile.CreateElement(objectElementName);

            foreach (SavedElement savedValue in dataset.data.savedElements)
            {
                XmlElement newElement = saveFile.CreateElement(savedValue.name);
                newElement.InnerText = savedValue.value;

                savedObjectElement.AppendChild(newElement);
            }

            documentRoot.AppendChild(savedObjectElement);

            objectsSaved++;
        }

        saveFile.AppendChild(documentRoot);

        saveFile.Save(filepath);

        saveComplete = true;
    }

    threadRunning = false;
}
```

More of the code can be found bellow if you want to reproduce the error.

SavedObject Class (Simplified):

```
//this class is in SavedObject.cs
public int id = 0;

public string name = "";
public string objectPath = "";

public bool saveData;
public bool loadData;

public bool savePosition;
public bool saveRotation;
public bool saveScale;

public SavedObjectData data = new SavedObjectData();

public GameObject parent;

public List<SavedElement> savedElements = new List<SavedElement>();

public void StoreData()
{
    data.id = id;

    data.name = name;
    data.objectPath = objectPath;

    data.saveData = saveData;
    data.loadData = loadData;

    data.savePosition = savePosition;
    data.saveRotation = saveRotation;
    data.saveScale = saveScale;

    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    data.position = position;

    Vector3 rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    data.rotation = rotation;

    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    data.scale = scale;
}

public void LoadData()
{
    id = data.id;

    name = data.name;
    objectPath = data.objectPath;

    saveData = data.saveData;
    loadData = data.loadData;

    savePosition = data.savePosition;
    saveRotation = data.saveRotation;
    saveScale = data.saveScale;

    if (savePosition) { transform.position = data.position; }
    if (saveRotation) { transform.eulerAngles = data.rotation; }
    if (saveScale) { transform.localScale = data.scale; }

    savedElements = data.savedElements;
}
```

SavedObjectData Class(simplified):

```
//this class is in SavedObject.cs
public int id;

public string name;
public string objectPath;

public bool saveData;
public bool loadData;

public bool savePosition;
public bool saveRotation;
public bool saveScale;

public Vector3 position;
public Vector3 rotation;
public Vector3 scale;

public List<SavedElement> savedElements = new List<SavedElement>();

public string BoolToString(bool value)
{
    string result = "";

    if (value)
    {
        result = "t";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "f";
    }

    return result;
}

public bool StringToBool(string value)
{
    bool result;

    if (value == "t")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

public void StoreValues()
{
    savedElements = new List<SavedElement>();

    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "ID", value = id.ToString() });

    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "Name", value = name });

    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "Path", value = objectPath });

    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "SD", value = BoolToString(saveData) });
    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "LD", value = BoolToString(loadData) });

    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "SP", value = BoolToString(savePosition) });
    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "SR", value = BoolToString(saveRotation) });
    savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "SS", value = BoolToString(saveScale) });

    if (savePosition) { savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "P", value = "x:" + position.x + "|y:" + position.y + "|z:" + position.z }); }

    if (saveRotation) { savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "R", value = "x:" + rotation.x + "|y:" + rotation.y + "|z:" + rotation.z }); }

    if (saveScale) { savedElements.Add(new SavedElement() { name = "S", value = "x:" + scale.x + "|y:" + scale.y + "|z:" + scale.z }); }
}

public void LoadValues()
{
    foreach (SavedElement savedElement in savedElements)
    {
        string[] sectionedData;

        switch (savedElement.name)
        {
            default:
                break;

            case "ID":
                id = int.Parse(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "Name":
                name = savedElement.value;
                break;

            case "Path":
                objectPath = savedElement.value;
                break;

            case "SD":
                saveData = StringToBool(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "LD":
                loadData = StringToBool(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "SP":
                savePosition = StringToBool(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "SR":
                saveRotation = StringToBool(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "SS":
                saveScale = StringToBool(savedElement.value);
                break;

            case "P":
                sectionedData = savedElement.value.Split('|');

                position = new Vector3(float.Parse(sectionedData[0].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[1].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[2].Split(':')[1]));
                break;

            case "R":
                sectionedData = savedElement.value.Split('|');

                rotation = new Vector3(float.Parse(sectionedData[0].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[1].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[2].Split(':')[1]));
                break;

            case "S":
                sectionedData = savedElement.value.Split('|');

                scale = new Vector3(float.Parse(sectionedData[0].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[1].Split(':')[1]), float.Parse(sectionedData[2].Split(':')[1]));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

SavedElement Class (simplified):

```
//this class is in SavedObject.cs
public string name;
public string value;
```

SaveData Class (simplified):

```
//this class is in SaveData.cs
private IEnumerator SaveObjects(string path, string rootElementName, string objectElementName, GameObject savedObjects){

    objects = new List<SavedObject>();

    //Compiles List
    foreach (Transform savedObject in savedObjects.transform)
    {
        if(savedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<SavedObject>() != null)
        {
            objects.add(savedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<SavedObject>())
        }
    }

    //Creates new instance of SaveSystem
    saveSystem = new SaveSystem
    {
        filepath = path,
        rootElementName = rootElementName,
        objectElementName = objectElementName,
        saveData = this,
        datasets = objects
    };

    //checks if saveSystem.datasets == objects then starts the thread to save the data
    //PLEASE NOTE: the reference is true but none of the data is updated and accessible
    saveSystem.StartSaveThread();

    while (saveSystem.threadRunning || saveSystem.syncingData)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

SaveSystem Class (simplified):

```
//this class is in SaveSystem.cs
public SaveData saveData;
public string filepath;
public string rootElementName;
public string objectElementName;
public int objectsSaved;
public List<SavedObject> datasets;

Thread saveThread;

public volatile bool threadRunning = false;
public volatile bool syncingData = false;

public void SaveData()
{
    bool saveComplete = false;
    threadRunning = true;

    while (threadRunning && saveComplete == false)
    {
        objectsSaved = 0;

        XmlDocument saveFile = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement documentRoot = saveFile.CreateElement(rootElementName);

        foreach (SavedObject dataset in datasets)
        {
            XmlElement savedObjectElement = saveFile.CreateElement(objectElementName);

            foreach (SavedElement savedValue in dataset.data.savedElements)
            {
                XmlElement newElement = saveFile.CreateElement(savedValue.name);
                newElement.InnerText = savedValue.value;

                savedObjectElement.AppendChild(newElement);
            }

            documentRoot.AppendChild(savedObjectElement);

            objectsSaved++;
        }

        saveFile.AppendChild(documentRoot);

        saveFile.Save(filepath);

        saveComplete = true;
    }

    threadRunning = false;
}

public void StartSaveThread()
{
    bool warned = false;

    //The error is here
    //The reference returns true but none of the data is accessible
    while(datasets != saveData.objects)
    {
        if(warned == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for data to sync");
            syncingData = true;
            warned = true;
        }
    }

    syncingData = false;

    saveThread = new Thread(SaveData);
    saveThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried coroutines?

Comment: yeah, when Save() is called it starts a coroutine that compiles the list and assigns it to a save system then starts the save thread and waits for it to finish.

Comment: It may help you get an answer if you show the code you're using. The best thing to do is provide a [mcve] which completely reproduces the issue

Comment: The compiled list usually has a count of 1000+ items, the data is being assigned correctly its just that it doesn't have enough time to update before the save thread starts.

Comment: Do you use a lock to guarantee only one thread has access to that instance (for *assigning*   and for *saving*)?

Comment: We need code or we are all just gonna be speculating here.

Comment: Your example (and code) seems overly complex.

Comment: Code and layout have been updated, the main piece of code you need to focus on is the first segment. But if you want to recreate it for your self you can use the other code provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd first make it easily reproducible, for example, start the thread, wait a second, and then assign the List variable so that you can reproduce the race condition constantly, by just letting the thread run first.

Perhaps change your logic so that you don't start your thread until after you know for certain the variable has been set, or you can use a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx object where the thread calls WaitOne(), which will block that thread on that line, until your List code path assigns the value and then calls the Set() event on the ManualResetEvent.